# Solution of ODE is also lip-continuous, if ODE is lip-continuous?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let G$ \subset \Bbb R \times \Bbb R^N$ and $f:G \to \Bbb R^N $continuous. Let $f$ be local lipschitz-continuous  in G.
>
> Show that the solution of the ODE $x'=f(t,x), x(\tau)=\xi$, which is $(t,\tau,\xi) \mapsto x(t,\tau,\xi)$ is local lipschitz-continuous in $\tau$, using Grönwall's inequality.

My attempt:
We can apply Picard-Lindelöf and know that there exists exact one solution to this ODE.

We know that $x'$ has got a solution then:
$x= \xi + \int_\tau^t f(s,x(s))ds  =\int_\tau^t f[s,x(s)- f(s,\xi)+ f(s,\xi)]ds $

Because $f$ is locally lipschitz, $f(s,\xi)$ is bounded on G.

Let $h:=max|f(t,\xi)|$ and $|x(t)-\xi|<\epsilon \forall t\in G$ ,then:

$|x-\xi|< \int_\tau^t f|(s,x(s))- f(s,\xi)|+ |f(s,\xi)|ds$ < $L \int_\tau^t[|x(s)-\xi|+h]ds$ <$\int_\tau^t(L\epsilon+h) ds$ <$(t-\tau)(L\epsilon+h)$ < $)<$$ c(L\epsilon+h)$

choose c= $(L\epsilon+h)^{-1}$ and I don't know how to go on or whether it is OK or not....any hint how to begin maybe or to continue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your interpretation of the task description might be off. You are to show 
$$|x(t;τ_1,ξ)-x(t;τ_2,ξ)|\le c(t)·|τ_1-τ_2|,$$
 where $x(t;τ_k,ξ)$ are the solutions with initial conditions $x(τ_k;τ_k,ξ)=ξ$.

Using Grönwall, one finds the standard estimate
$$
|x(t;τ_1,ξ)-x(t;τ_2,ξ)|\le e^{L|t-τ_2|}·|x(τ_2;τ_1,ξ)-ξ|
$$

Thus it remains to find a bound for $|x(τ_2;τ_1,ξ)-ξ|$. But that is just
$$
|x(τ_2;τ_1,ξ)-ξ|\le \int_{τ_1}^{τ_2}|f(s,x(s;τ_1,ξ))|\,ds\le \sup|f|·|τ_1-τ_2|
$$
where the supremum is over some bounded subset of $G$.